# rich:autocomplete don't show the list

Tags: jsf, autocomplete, xhtml, richfaces

I´m trying to implement a richfaces autocomplete component, the problem i have is that the autocompleteMethod is never called.

```
                <rich:autocomplete id="formacode" styleClass="champ_select310" layout="list" 
                autocompleteList="#{enregistrementFormationsMBean.toShow}" 
                autocompleteMethod="#{enregistrementFormationsMBean.autocomplete}" 
                value="#{enregistrementFormationsMBean.formacode}">
                </rich:autocomplete>
```

the MBean:

```
public String getFormacode() {
    return testDto.getFormacode();
}

public void setFormacode(String formacode) {
    testDto.setFormacode(formacode);
}
public List<String> getToShow() {
    return testDto.getToShow();
}

public void setToShow(List<String> toShow) {
    testDto.setToShow(toShow);
}

public List<String> autocomplete(String prefix) {
    Map<String, String> map;
    List<String> listOfItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        map = testFacade.getFormacode(prefix);

        for (Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
            listOfItems.add(e.getValue());
        }
    } catch (RemoteException | ServiceException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    setToShow(listOfItems);
    return listOfItems;
}
```

When i debug, the getter getToShow and the function autocomplete are never called.

I am using richfaces 4.3.3

ps: in the log

```
ERROR [com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.MissingResourceImpl] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) Resource handler=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.ResourceHandlerOuterImpl@73ceed1] was unable to create a resource for resourceName=[AutocompleteBase.js] libraryName=[org.richfaces.images] contentType=[null]
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5) JSF1064 : Impossible de localiser ou de servir une ressource, Autocomplete.js, depuis la biblioth├¿que org.richfaces.images
```

thank's for your help !!

Comment: Looks like a problem with resources, is any Ajax request firing?

Comment: the html output :
<input id="A1969:j_idt15:formacodeInput" class="rf-au-fnt rf-au-inp " type="text" name="A1969:j_idt15:formacodeInput" autocomplete="off">